# How to disable "picture in picture" on html5 video in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

The html element `video` has an attribute called `disablePictureInPicture` which works perfectly fine although it seems to only work in chrome.

Since I could only find old posts on this which didn't end up in a fix or workaround I'm asking here again.

Do you know a fix/workaround for this issue?

Comment: Given the question above - in particular "disable 'picture in picture'" - I would still be interested in an answer.

Comment: @qxotk As far as i know there hasn't been a fix nor a workaround to this yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox 116+<sup>[3](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1811321#c9), [4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/disablePictureInPicture#browser_compatibility)</sup> or 118+<sup>[5](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1865748#c0)</sup> added partial support with true value.

---

For Firefox 115 and older:

This was recently [discussed on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611831#c5) with this result:

> (at this time) we're not planning on implementing or shipping any part
> of the Picture-in-Picture Web API

But I found that some websites with videos in the background do not have the pip button. They do it by removing all audio streams from the video, which results in firefox not displaying the button. Obviously this will not work for all use cases, but it might be useful in some situations.

You can do this e.g. using ffmpeg like described in [this](https://superuser.com/a/268986) question.

Comment: Update: Visiting Bugzilla on the date of this comment, the status of the bug reported as "disablePictureInPicture attribute does not work" has a status of "RESOLVED WONTFIX " - so "disablePictureInPicture" attribute is (as stated by @zuim) will *not* be a means to achieve this.

Comment: @qxotk This answer was meant to clarify that there intentionally is no way to disable the pip button (like you also found). 
But I also described a workaround, which works in at least some cases and which I did not find documented anywhere else. So this answers the "workaround" part of the question imho.

Answer (score 0):

It should works with 118+ `disablePictureInPicture="true"`: https://bugzil.la/1811321

Also interested: https://bugzil.la/1863583

```html
<h3>Video Sample Page</h3>

<p>This is the video we will work with. It uses disablePictureInPicture="true"</p>
<div id="container">
  <video id='video' disablePictureInPicture="true" controls="controls" preload="none" width="600" poster="https://assets.codepen.io/32795/poster.png">
    <source id='mp4' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>
</div> <!-- End Container -->
```

Firefox  results: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/disablePictureInPicture#browser_compatibility

| 115 ESR | 116.0.3 | 120 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Failed (mess at [bugzilla](https://bugzil.la/1811321#c9)) | Failed at Windows 7 | Works at Windows 11 |

Someone can try in 117.0 or 117.0.1 at Windows 10, macOS or GNU/Linux.

Comment: Does not work on linux
- FireFox Version 121.0

Comment: You can report at bugzilla, I am not mother Teresa to install same distro.

Comment: Okay, you mentioned can someone try GNU/Linux so I tried it for you, don't get all rude on me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Firefox go to this url `about:config`.
2. You can see that says "This might void your warranty" Click on the "I accept the risk" button to proceed the step.
3. Then in search bar, type `media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.enabled` and Double-click on the entry to change the value. If it's already set to `true`, double-clicking will change it to `false`.

That's It.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with this, I don't support Mozilla decision to not follow spec and mark this as WONTFIX, but I found that for use cases when you have  with no controls but want to keep context menu and remove picture-in-picture floating button, use `pointer-events: all;` CSS attribute or `pointer-events: none;` to remote both floating button and context menu.